# C++ For statement not executing designated number of times

Tags: c++

I have a random word generator and it is supposed to run `input` number of times, but it isn't doing that. If I had my `input` set to 10 it would only run `2-3` times, inside of my for statement I have also tried using a `while` statement.

Here is my  code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <random>

int random_number(int min, int max) {
    int output = min + (rand() % static_cast<int>(max - min + 1));
    return output;
}

std::string random_syllable() {

    int line_num = random_number(1, 50);
    int x = 0;
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream myfile("sylla.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while (getline(myfile, line)) {
            x += 1;
            if (line_num == x) {
                return line;
            }
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    return "ERROR";
}

char random_consonant() {
    int x = 0;
    char letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
    while (x == 0) {
        if ((letter == 'x') || (letter == 'q') || (letter == 'f') || (letter == 'w') || (letter == 'd')) {
            char letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
        }
        else {
            char letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
            x = 1;
        }
    }
    return letter;
}

char random_vowel() {
    char letter;
    int x = random_number(1, 5);
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        letter = 'x';
        break;

    case 2:
        letter = 'q';
        break;

    case 3:
        letter = 'f';
        break;

    case 4:
        letter = 'w';
        break;

    case 5:
        letter = 'd';
        break;
    }
    return letter;
}

char random_letter2() {
    char letter;
    int x = random_number(1, 5);
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
        letter = 'l';
        break;

    case 2:
        letter = 'n';
        break;

    case 3:
        letter = 'r';
        break;

    case 4:
        letter = 's';
        break;

    case 5:
        letter = 'y';
        break;
    }
    return letter;
}

int main() {

    // Consonant - Syllable - (vowel) - (l,n,r,s,y) - ((')-(vowel)-(consonant)-(Syllable))

    srand(time(NULL));
    std::string word;
    int x = 0;
    double input = 0;

    input = 10;

    for (double i = 0; i < input; i = i + 1) {
        word = "";
        word = word + random_consonant();
        word = word + random_syllable();
        x = random_number(1, 2);
        if (x == 1) {
            word = word + random_vowel();
            word = word + random_letter2();
        }
        x = random_number(1, 10);
        if (x <= 3) {
            word = word + "'";
            word = word + random_vowel();
            word = word + random_syllable();
        }
        std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    /*
    ifstream file("FILE NAME HERE"); // syllables
    while (getline(file, line))
    count++;
    */

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

** sylla.txt is just a file full of syllables

Comment: Do you know what vowels actually are? Last I checked, they were, a, e, i, o, and u (And h/y, possibly)

Comment: please provide the smallest code possible that shows the problem you have

Comment: why is `input` a `double`?

Comment: was testing to see if double was better than int

Comment: @ArnavBorborah, this is just for testing purposes

Comment: Is it getting stuck in an infinite loop inside random_consonant?

Comment: doesn't seem to be

Comment: [It actually is stuck in an infinite loop.](https://repl.it/repls/BeneficialDeadlyIbadanmalimbe)

Comment: how could I fix that?

Comment: Warning: `double`s make very poor tests in a conditional because they are not always exact numbers. More here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Here you are testing less than which won't screw up too badly, but in the case of equals you'll find you often do not hit the target dead on.

Comment: If I wanted to generate a random letter, I would create an array of all possible _valid_ characters, generate a random index, and get the character at that index. This requires no checking for valid letters, and would shorten the corresponding function significantly.

Comment: Expanding on @ArnavBorborah 's comment with a link to t[he wiki page for the Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It is very similar, so you can steal ideas from it.

Comment: Thanks that worked! :)

Comment: Don't just tell him. Jeez people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You redeclare `letter` in `random_consonant`, so you only check against the outer scope's `letter` variable, but assign to an unused `letter` variable scoped only to the if or else statment.  Removing the extra `char` should prevent that:

```
char random_consonant() {
    int x = 0;
    char letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
    while (x == 0) {
        if ((letter == 'x') || (letter == 'q') || (letter == 'f') || (letter == 'w') || (letter == 'd')) {
            letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
        }
        else {
            letter = char(random_number(97, 122));
            x = 1;
        }
    }
    return letter;
}
```